# GeoJSON mapping discrepancies between d3 and Leaflet

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, geojson

My objective is to use d3 to generate svg paths for each feature in a given GeoJSON feature collection.

When I map the paths using leaflet, all the features look perfect.

```
d3.json("ct_counties.geo.json", function(data) {
    var leaflet_paths = leaflet_map.addLayer(new L.GeoJSON(data));
});
```

[image: two maps]

But when I map the paths using d3, some of the features look wrong.

```
d3.json("ct_counties.geo.json", function(collection) {
    var bounds = d3.geo.bounds(collection);

    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(project);

    var feature = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(collection.features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr('class','county');

    d3_map.on("viewreset", reset);

    reset();

    function project(x) {
      var point = d3_map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(x[1], x[0]));
      return [point.x, point.y];
    }

    function reset() {
      var bottomLeft = project(bounds[0]); 
      var topRight = project(bounds[1]);
      svg.attr("width", topRight[0] - bottomLeft[0])
        .attr("height", bottomLeft[1] - topRight[1])
        .style("margin-left", bottomLeft[0] + "px")
        .style("margin-top", topRight[1] + "px");
      g.attr("transform", "translate(" + -bottomLeft[0] + "," + -topRight[1] + ")");
      feature.attr("d", path);
    }
});
```

View the map differences [here](http://s2t2.github.com/freezing-bear/).

And refer to the full code [here](https://github.com/s2t2/freezing-bear/blob/master/index.html).

Since both maps use the same feature collection, why is the d3 version wrong?

Comment: Looks like the polygons are interpreted differently. Due to the order of the points probably. Upon closer inspection, looks like one point is missing from each polygon. Probably the bit where the end gets glued to the start?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

D3 is not wrong, the data is incorrect and Leaflet is more lenient.

Taking Litchfield (top left county) as an example:

```
{
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
        "kind" : "county",
        "name" : "Litchfield",
        "state" : "CT"
    },
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates" : [ [ [ [ -73.0535, 42.0390 ], [ -73.0097, 42.0390 ],
                [ -73.0316, 41.9678 ], [ -72.8892, 41.9733 ],
                [ -72.9385, 41.8966 ], [ -72.9495, 41.8090 ],
                [ -73.0152, 41.7981 ], [ -72.9823, 41.6392 ],
                [ -73.1631, 41.5571 ], [ -73.1576, 41.5133 ],
                [ -73.3219, 41.5078 ], [ -73.3109, 41.4694 ],
                [ -73.3876, 41.5133 ], [ -73.4424, 41.4914 ],
                [ -73.4862, 41.6447 ], [ -73.5191, 41.6666 ],
                [ -73.4862, 42.0500 ] ] ] ]
    }
}
```

The multipolygon is not closed, its end does not equal the beginning.
I've plotted the coordinates, marking the first coordinate red, and the last one green:
[image: points in the multipolygon]

As you can see, the last coordinate gets discarded by d3.

The [GeoJSON specification](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#linestring) says

> A LinearRing is closed LineString with 4 or more positions. The first and last positions are equivalent (they represent equivalent points).

So d3 has a point (no pun intended) and the MultiPolygon should be closed by adding the start coordinate at the end:

```
...[ -73.4862, 42.0500 ], [ -73.0535, 42.0390 ] ] ] ]
```

Comment: Thanks @flup. One point of clarification: I wasn't suggesting d3 as a framework was wrong; rather, I was referring to my d3 map implementation.